# Cuantos archivos se pueden guardar en github

Tags: git, github

Git hub tiene un limites de archivos? Me refiero a subir varios proyectos en git hub. Cuantos puedo subir? Porque mi idea es que cada practica que haga subirlo a github.

Soy principiante, aclaro esto porque no son proyectos grandes los que pienso subir por ahora ya que no cuento con el conocimiento.

Otra pregunta es si debo crear una cuenta aparte para que no se mezclen mis practicas de todos los días con los proyectos para mi portfolio.

Perdón por las preguntas básicas. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Siempre es sano comenzar por leer la [documentación oficial](https://docs.github.com/en/github/managing-large-files/what-is-my-disk-quota). Suele estar hecha por otros programadores pensando en este tipo de preguntas :)  Sobre el tener dos cuentas, tú puedes crear cada repositorio en tu cuenta actual  y definir si es público o privado (así, los privados no se verían en tu portafolio, por ejemplo)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Perdón por las preguntas básicas. Muchas gracias.

Son preguntas básicas, pero más que la respuesta concreta pienso que apuntan a una duda muy válida que no se aborda explícitamente.

> Git hub tiene un limites de archivos? Me refiero a subir varios proyectos en git hub. Cuantos puedo subir? Porque mi idea es que cada practica que haga subirlo a github.

Puedes subir todos los archivos que quieras en tus repos.

Si bien no hay un límite sobre la cantidad de archivos, proyectos, commits, ramas y organizaciones, hay un límite en el tamaño de cada archivo. No te aceptará poner en control de versiones algo que pese más de (creo) 100MB. Si un proyecto lo requiere Github tiene un servicio de LFS (large file storage).

Github también permite publicar paquetes para ofrecerlos en descarga descentralizada al estilo NPM/Rubygems/PyPi y este tipo de alojamiento está fuera del alcance del control de versiones. Ellos te dan espacio gratuito para paquetes de unos 500 megas, y eso alcanza para mucho.

Si bien la idea no es usar a Github para mantener tu colección de películas sin gastar ni un veinte (eso sería ineficiente, en realidad), Github sí permite, facilita e incentiva que los uses para alojar tus sitios web, o simplemente los archivos estáticos de tu web. No es tan rápido como para montar el próximo instagram en infraestructura ajena pero sirve.

> Otra pregunta es si debo crear una cuenta aparte para que no se mezclen mis practicas de todos los días con los proyectos para mi portfolio.

Hasta hace unos años había tres tipos de membresías:

- usuario gratuito: podía tener infinitos repos públicos
- usuario de pago: podía además tener infinitos repos privados
- cuenta organización: puede crear repos para trabajar en conjunto varios usuarios, segmentando su tipo de permisos (y otras cosas).

Por ahí por el 2015 los repos privados se volvieron gratuitos, y eso te permite  jugar con la condición de públicos o privados de tus repos si quieres presentarlos u olvidarlos.

[A partir del año pasado las cuentas de organización también tienen un tier gratuito](https://docs.github.com/en/github/setting-up-and-managing-organizations-and-teams/about-organizations), de modo que puedes con una sola cuenta crear una organización para tu portfolio, otra para tu club de programación y otra personal.

No hay que andarse creando más de una cuenta. La idea de git (no sólo github) es mantener una trazabilidad en muchos aspectos, de entre los cuales el autor de cada commit es relevante.